# AAD application permissions to enable creating other AAD application

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

What OAuth API and permissions  are required by an AAD application so that I can use it to authorize creating new AAD application as described in this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#ApplicationEntity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the app this permission on the Azure AD Graph API:

> Manage apps that this app creates or owns

It is an app permission that allows the app to create applications and manage them. It does not allow it to manage other applications.

I created an app with this app permission, granted the permissions, got a token with client credentials flow and was able to create an app in my directory. So can confirm it should work once you get the permission granted.

Comment: No luck, I keep getting 403 Unauthorized > {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd, I'll have to try this later. Also, you should try again in a few minutes as sometimes Azure AD gives tokens without the newest permissions for a while.

Comment: Wait, just realized I'm not able to granting the permission in the tenant I'm testing, I'll get back to you after I give your solution a try (after an admin grants the permission to my AAD app)

Comment: :D That would lead to problems! This requires admin consent!

Comment: I tested this just now and it works 100%, should work for you once you get the permission granted.

Comment: Confirmed, works as expected, thank you for actually going ahead and testing this too, much appreciated :)